# I have a multi-dimensional array of doubles (Double[][]) created in a child class and I need to print this array in parent class

Tags: java, arrays, methods

All of my main methods take place in this class:

```
package wk2individual;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Wk2Individual {
        public static void main(String[] args) {   
        AnnualPayCalculator aPC = new AnnualPayCalculator();
        SalesPerson sP = new SalesPerson(); 
        //System greeting    
          Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);  
            System.out.println ("Welcome to the Employee Annual Pay calculator!");

        //user input
            System.out.println("Please enter the name of the first sales employee:");
                sP.salesPerson1 = sc.next();    

            System.out.println ("Please enter " + sP.salesPerson1 + "'s total sales for the year:"); 
                aPC.totalSales1 = sc.nextDouble();

        //begin outputs    
            if (aPC.totalSales1 >= 112000 && aPC.totalSales1 < 140000) {
                System.out.println(sP.salesPerson1 + " has earned $" + aPC.total1() + " in "
                        + "commissions for the year! " + sP.salesPerson1 + "'s total pay for the "
                        + "year will be $" + aPC.total2()); //outputs employees commission and pay if sales meet incentive
            }
            else if (aPC.totalSales1 >= 140000) {
                System.out.println(sP.salesPerson1 + " has earned $" + aPC.total3() + " in "
                        + "commissions for the year! " + sP.salesPerson1 + "'s total pay for the "
                        + "year will be $" + aPC.total4()); //outputs employees commission and pay if sales exceed targetSales
            }
            else if (aPC.totalSales1 < 112000) {
                System.out.println(sP.salesPerson1 + " will receive a total pay of $" + 
                        aPC.fixedSalary + " for the year. " + sP.salesPerson1 + " did not meet "
                        + "the sales incentive to earn commission for the year."); /*outputs employees end of year pay as fixed 
    salary since the sales amount is less than 80% of the sales target*/
            }

        //begin the inputs for the second salesperson        
            System.out.println("Now let's get the name of the second sales employee:");
                sP.salesPerson2 = sc.next();

            System.out.println("Please enter " + sP.salesPerson2 + "'s total sales for the year:");
                aPC.totalSales2 = sc.nextDouble();

            //begin outputs    
            if (aPC.totalSales2 >= 112000 && aPC.totalSales2 < 140000) {
                System.out.println(sP.salesPerson2 + " has earned $" + aPC.total5() + " in "
                        + "commissions for the year! " + sP.salesPerson2 + "'s total pay for the "
                        + "year will be $" + aPC.total6()); //outputs employees commission and pay if sales meet incentive
            }
            else if (aPC.totalSales2 >= 140000) {
                System.out.println(sP.salesPerson2 + " has earned $" + aPC.total7() + " in "
                        + "commissions for the year! " + sP.salesPerson2 + "'s total pay for the "
                        + "year will be $" + aPC.total8()); //outputs employees commission and pay if sales exceed targetSales
            }
            else if (aPC.totalSales2 < 112000) {
                System.out.println(sP.salesPerson2 + " will receive a total pay of $" + 
                        aPC.fixedSalary + " for the year. " + sP.salesPerson2 + " did not meet "
                        + "the sales incentive to earn commission for the year."); /*outputs employees end of year pay as fixed 
    salary since the sales amount is less than 80% of the sales target*/        
            }
//This is where I am trying to print the array created in the SalesPerson class
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Here are both employee's sales in comparison:");
        System.out.println(sP.salesPerson1 + "\t" + sP.salesPerson2);
        System.out.print(n);      
        } 
     }
```

I created the AnnualPayCalculator class to hold the totals and calculations:

```
package wk2individual;

public class AnnualPayCalculator 
{
         double totalSales1, totalSales2, employee1TotalPay, employee2TotalPay;
         double fixedSalary = 75000.00;        
         final double commissionRate = .25;
         double salesTarget = 140000;
         double accelerationFactor = .3125;

        double total1(){
         double incentiveCommission = totalSales1 * commissionRate;
         return incentiveCommission;
        }
        double total2(){   
         double employee1TotalPay = total1() + fixedSalary;
         return employee1TotalPay; 
        }
        double total3(){
         double targetCommission = totalSales1 * accelerationFactor;
         return targetCommission; 
        }
        double total4(){
         double employee1TotalPay = total3() + fixedSalary;
         return employee1TotalPay;
        }
        double total5(){
         double incentiveCommission = totalSales2 * commissionRate;
         return incentiveCommission;
        }
        double total6(){
         double employee2TotalPay = total5() + fixedSalary;
         return employee2TotalPay;
        }
        double total7(){
         double targetCommission = totalSales2 * accelerationFactor;
         return targetCommission;
        }
        double total8(){
         double employee2TotalPay = total7() + fixedSalary;
         return employee2TotalPay;
        }
}
```

Then I created this SalesPerson class in which holds my array:

```
package wk2individual;

public class SalesPerson {    
    String salesPerson1, salesPerson2;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    AnnualPayCalculator aPC = new AnnualPayCalculator();
        Double[][] sales = new Double[2][2];

        sales[0][0] = aPC.totalSales1;
        sales[0][1] = aPC.totalSales2;
        sales[1][0] = aPC.employee1TotalPay;
        sales[1][1] = aPC.employee2TotalPay;

     printArray(sales);   
    };

private static void printArray(Double[][] numbers){
    for (Double[] n : numbers){
       System.out.print(n);  
    }    
}
```

In the first class I am able to print the totals of the calculations defined in the AnnualPayCalculator class. How can I print the array in the first class?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing. It appears all your code is in a single class; where's the other? The method to print the arrays is private so no outside class can call it directly. I wouldn't do it this away though. I wouldn't think it's a sales person responsibility to print arrays. I also wouldn't suggest naming the class singular when it's actually plural nor would I make variable like `totalSalesN`.

Comment: To begin with, I don't think this is a child class. It's just a `class` called `SalesPerson` with entry point `main` . Now what is parent class `AnnualPayCalculator` ? That is also another object/class where you want call the `printArray()` .Right ?

Comment: So I have updated the post and provided all that I have thus far. Hope that clarifies things a bit. Thanks for answering so quickly!

Comment: I don't see any hierarchical relationship among those classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't want 2 `main` methods. When you create an object of `SalesPerson` in `Wk2Individual`, the 2d array `sales` is not being declared because static methods and variables are not part of instances/objects of classes. So what you might want to do is make a non-static method in `SalesPerson` like this;

```
public class SalesPerson {    
    String salesPerson1, salesPerson2;

    public void createSales(AnnualPayCalculator aPC) {
        // you don't need to create aPC
        // AnnualPayCalculator aPC = new AnnualPayCalculator();

        Double[][] sales = new Double[2][2];

        sales[0][0] = aPC.totalSales1;
        sales[0][1] = aPC.totalSales2;
        sales[1][0] = aPC.employee1TotalPay;
        sales[1][1] = aPC.employee2TotalPay;
        printArray(sales);   
    }
}
```

Also, you are probably trying to use the values from the `aPC` object in the `Wk2Individual` class. But you are creating a new instance of the object instead. So you should pass the old `aPC` object from `Wk2Individual` class like this:

```
System.out.println("");
System.out.println("Here are both employee's sales in comparison:");
System.out.println(sP.salesPerson1 + "\t" + sP.salesPerson2);
sP.createSales(aPC);
```

This will send the aPC object with all the calculated values to the `createSales()` of `SalesPerson` class where your 2d array will be created.

Now you need to print this. To do that create a `print` method in the `SalesPerson` class:

```
private void printArray(Double[][] numbers){
    for (Double[] n : numbers){
        System.out.print(n);  
    }    
}
```

But you cannot print an array like that. So do this:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(n));
```

In `AnnualPayCalculator` class you have several methods which use the **global** variables: `employee1TotalPay` and `employee2TotalPay`. For example, the method `total2()`. In these methods, you are creating yet another variable with the same name. In `total2()` you are creating `employee1TotalPay` which *shadows* the global variable `employee1TotalPay`. It means that if inside that method you use `employee1TotalPay` anywhere, it will use the **local** `employee1TotalPay` variable (the one you created inside the method). To use the global variable either remove the declaration of the local variable:

```
employee1TotalPay = total1() + fixedSalary;
```

or use the `this` keyword to access the global variables:

```
this.employee1TotalPay = total1() + fixedSalary;
```

Comment: This worked! Only now, the array prints a value of 0 in the second row for each employeeTotalPay. I believe it is because in the aPC class there are 2 totals for employeeTotalPay(There are 2 totals for employee1TotalPay and 2 totals for employee2TotalPay). I need the program to take the correct outcome and put it in to the array.

Comment: @Megan It is showing 0 because you have not updated the value of `employeeTotalPay` (1 and 2, both). These values have not even been initialized. So the default value for `double` is 0. I'm editing my answer to include what you are doing wrong

Comment: Thank you so much!! Seeing it now, I am kind of mad that I have been trying to figure this out for a week lol! Everything you provided was exactly what I needed and I can't thank you enough for helping me! You are a real life saver!!